# ksh: shell script to search for a string in all files present in a directory at a regular interval

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a directory (output) in unix (SUN). There are two types of files created with timestamp prefix to the file name. These file are created on a regular interval of 10 minutes.
e. g:

```
1.  20140129_170343_fail.csv (some lines are there)
2.  20140129_170343_success.csv (some lines are there)
```

Now I have to search for a particular string in all the files present in the output directory and if the string is found in fail and success files, I have to count the number of lines present in those files and save the output to the `cnt_succ` and `cnt_fail` variables. If the string is not found I will search again in the same directory after a sleep timer of 20 seconds.

here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for i in 1 2
do
  grep -l 0140127_123933_part_hg_log_status.csv /osp/local/var/log/tool2/final_logs/* >log_t.txt;  ###  log_t.txt will contain all the matching file list
  while read line   ### reading the log_t.txt
  do
    echo "$line has following count"
    CNT=`wc -l $line|tr -s " "|cut -d" " -f2`
    CNT=`expr $CNT - 1`
    echo $CNT
  done <log_t.txt
  if [ $CNT > 0 ]
  then
    exit
  fi

  echo "waiitng"
  sleep 20
done
```

The problem I'm facing is, I'm not able to get the _success and _fail in file in line and and check their count

Comment: Are you looking to do this in [tag:ksh] or [tag:bash]?

Comment: Its ksh not the bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I'm able to find the solution. Here is the complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh


file_name="0140127_123933.csv"

for i in 1 2
do

grep -l $file_name /osp/local/var/log/tool2/final_logs/* >log_t.txt;

    while read line
    do
    if [ $(echo "$line" |awk '/success/') ]           ## will check the success file
    then
    CNT_SUCC=`wc -l $line|tr -s " "|cut -d" " -f2`
    CNT_SUCC=`expr $CNT_SUCC - 1`

    fi

    if [ $(echo "$line" |awk '/fail/') ]             ## will check the fail file
    then
    CNT_FAIL=`wc -l $line|tr -s " "|cut -d" " -f2`
    CNT_FAIL=`expr $CNT_FAIL - 1`

    fi
    done <log_t.txt
    if [ $CNT_SUCC > 0 ] && [ $CNT_FAIL > 0 ]
    then
            echo " Fail count = $CNT_FAIL"
            echo " Success count =  $CNT_SUCC"
            exit
    fi

   echo "waitng for next search..."
   sleep 10
   done
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @PrvejKhan You should mark this as best answer by clicking the check mark next to it, so the question appears solved.

Comment: it says : I need to wait for next 15 hrs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about `ksh`, but `while ... do; ... done` is notorious for running off with whatever variables you're using in `bash`. `ksh` might be similar.

If I've understand your question right, SunOS has `grep`, `uniq` and `sort` AFAIK, so a possible alternative might be...

First of all:

```
$ cat fail.txt
W34523TERG
ADFLKJ
W34523TERG
WER
ASDTQ34T
DBVSER6
W34523TERG
ASDTQ34T
DBVSER6

$ cat success.txt
abcde
defgh
234523452
vxczvzxc
jkl
vxczvzxc
asdf
234523452
vxczvzxc
dlkjhgl
jkl
wer
234523452
vxczvzxc
```

And now:

```
egrep "W34523TERG|ASDTQ34T" fail.txt | sort | uniq -c
    2 ASDTQ34T
    3 W34523TERG

egrep "234523452|vxczvzxc|jkl" success.txt | sort | uniq -c
    3 234523452
    2 jkl
    4 vxczvzxc
```

Depending on the input data, you may want to see what options `sort` has on your system. Examining `uniq`'s options may prove useful too (it can do more than just count duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

Think you want something like this (will work in both [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh))

```
#!/bin/ksh

while read -r file; do
  lines=$(wc -l < "$file")
  ((sum+=$lines))
done < <(grep -Rl --include="[1|2]*_fail.csv" "somestring")
echo "$sum"
```

Note this will match files starting with `1` or `2` and ending in `_fail.csv`, not exactly clear if that's what you want or not.

e.g. Let's say I have two files, one starting with `1` (containing 4 lines) and one starting with `2` (containing 3 lines), both ending in `_fail.csv somewhere under my current working directory

```
> abovescript
7
```

Important to understand grep options here

```
   -R, --dereference-recursive
          Read all files under each directory,  recursively.   Follow  all
          symbolic links, unlike -r.
```

and

```
   -l, --files-with-matches
          Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print the name of each input
          file from which output would normally have  been  printed.   The
          scanning  will  stop  on  the  first match.  (-l is specified by
          POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'm getting it right, but You can't diffrinciate the files?

maybe try:

```
#...
CNT=`expr $CNT - 1`
if [ $(echo $line | grep -o "fail") ]
then
    #do something with fail count
else
    #do something with success count
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. 
I'm sorry but the -o option is not working on sunOs.