# ksh: shell script to search for a string in all files present in a directory at a regular interval and avoid the repetition

Tags: file, unix, scripting, grep, ksh

I have asked a question earlier. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449699/ksh-shell-script-to-search-for-a-string-in-all-files-present-in-a-directory-at) to that question.

The problem I'm facing now is that the searched string can be present in the multiple number of success/fail files and the script display the result from the previously generated files. My task is to pick the latest files (success and fail) **only** from the directory and displayed the result.
Code from previous solved question :

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

file_name="140127_123933.csv"

for i in 1 2
do

grep -l $file_name /osp/local/var/log/tool2/final_logs/* >log_t.txt; 
while read line
do
if [ $(echo "$line" |awk '/success/') ]           ## will check the success file
then
CNT_SUCC=`wc -l $line|tr -s " "|cut -d" " -f2`
CNT_SUCC=`expr $CNT_SUCC - 1`

fi

if [ $(echo "$line" |awk '/fail/') ]             ## will check the fail file
then
CNT_FAIL=`wc -l $line|tr -s " "|cut -d" " -f2`
CNT_FAIL=`expr $CNT_FAIL - 1`

fi
done <log_t.txt
if [ $CNT_SUCC > 0 ] && [ $CNT_FAIL > 0 ]
then
        echo " Fail count = $CNT_FAIL"
        echo " Success count =  $CNT_SUCC"
        exit
fi

echo "waitng for next search..."
sleep 10
done
```

final_logs directory contains the result files, generated by another task  **P1** by processing this **140127_123933.csv** types of file.
Actually the P1 process the file **140127_123933.csv** and dump the result in two different files (success and fail) in final_logs directory. The process P1 dump the **140127_123933.csv** name in those two files as the first line.
As long as the **140127_123933.csv** file given to process to task P1 is unique, my code is working fine. But the problem occurs when the same file **140127_123933.csv** is processed by the task P1 again after some time. Now there are total 4 files (2 success and 2 fail) that contain this particular string. My code will display the result from the previously created success and fail files and not from the recently created files.
A quick response from your side will be highly appreciated. Please feel free if you need any other information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're looping twice. You can reduce that code (disregarding the outer loop)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

search_name="140127_123933.csv"
cnt_success=0
cnt_fail=0

for file in /osp/local/var/log/tool2/final_logs/*; do
    if [[ "$(head -1 "$file")" == "$search_name" ]]; 
        case "$file" in
            *success*) (( cnt_success++ )) ;;
            *fail*)    (( cnt_fail++ )) ;;
        esac
    fi
done
```